# ZXing.Net ITF Barcode issues Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, zxing, barcode-scanner

I can successfully decode barcodes ITF using ZXing.Net, but in some cases the Result.Text have some missing numbers, like in this:

original barcode: 836900000008262500403007233338786038100661049195

Result.Text       : 83690000000  26250040300  23333878603  10066104919

In this case there are missing a 8,7,8 and 5

In this other case, the numbers are reordered to a random order and have some missing numbers:

original barcode: 23793381285017475716618000050809162310000010000

Result.Text         23791623100000100003381250174757161800005080

Any ideas why is it happening?

Thanks

### EDIT: 06/12/2015

If I don't specify the PossibleFormats the decoder decodes all the codes (the images are here:1drv.ms/1B6wD5c) as ITF and the result is the same as the described above. The code I'm using is here:

```
    public BarCodeReaderService(IDialogService _dialogService)
    {
        dialogService = _dialogService;

        barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader
        {
            Options = new DecodingOptions
            {
                PureBarcode = true,
                TryHarder = true,
                PossibleFormats = new BarcodeFormat[] { BarcodeFormat.ITF }
            },

        };
    }

    public async Task<string> ScanBitmapAsync(StorageFile file)
    {
        string result = null;
        using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            // initialize with 1,1 to get the current size of the image
            var writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
            writeableBmp.SetSource(stream);
            // and create it again because otherwise the WB isn't fully initialized and decoding
            // results in a IndexOutOfRange
            writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap(writeableBmp.PixelWidth, writeableBmp.PixelHeight);
            stream.Seek(0);
            writeableBmp.SetSource(stream);


            try
            {
                result = ScanBitmap(writeableBmp);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                dialogService.ShowAsync("Ocorreu um erro \n" + ex.Message, "Erro");
            }
        }

        return result != null ? result : null;
    }

    private string ScanBitmap(WriteableBitmap writeableBmp)
    {

        var result = barcodeReader.Decode(writeableBmp);

        return result != null ? result.Text : null;
    }
```

Comment: I need a sample image for analyzing

Comment: The ITF barcodes I'm trying to read are from Brazilian Bank slip, like credit card, water bill, etc. The images are at http://1drv.ms/1B6wD5c

Comment: All sample barcodes are working fine for me. I tried two other online decoders which are giving the same results. In my opinion your "original barcode" values are wrong. I don't know where you got them. But the numbers you are missing are not included in the barcode. They are only printed in the human readable text. Perhaps they have another meaning.

Comment: The values are printed in the Bank slip, maybe they are validation numbers, usable only when the code is typed. I will do some research now that I know the problem isn't with the Decoder. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing numbers are indeed validation numbers and they have to be calculated.